# I need to import only tables from another html/php page

Tags: php, html, css

I have a page complete with a php library, header, etc that I need to import only a couple of tables and information from onto another page that will be displayed on a screen so it'll need to be formatted differently (tables side by side instead of vertically).

Basically I want to be able to only have to update the main page's table info.

How do I do this? I'm assuming I'll have to use an include but I don't know how to include only the tables from the other page. Once I complete that I'll have to use CSS to format the tables differently?

Thank you.

Comment: If you don't want to pull the data dynamically from a database, then yes, store the table code in one file then use `include` to insert it in both places. This will give you 3 files: one containing only the table and two places where the table data is included. CSS will allow you to format the underlying HTML code differently in both places. You're on the right track.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why Don't you separate the table from both pages and include it in both of them, then you can use different styles on each page.

```
<html>
page 1


<?php

include('table.php');

?>

</html>
```

or

```
<html>
page 2

<?php

include('table.php');

?>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what data you are going to show in the tables.If you want to show different data for different tables Then you cannot include them. You must have to use different table.
But if u want to show a common table then u can take the table in a separate php file and u have to write

```
include(table.php)
```

In different pages u want to add the particular table. Then u can change the styling as u want.
U have to keep that in different div classes for different pages and and do styling like

```
.divclass1 table{..}
.divclass2 table{..}
```